# Read .txt file and store in 2-D char array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, text-files

I am kind of stuck. How do I get this to work or are there a better way? Please give code examples.

```
public char[][] charmap = new char[SomeInts.amount][SomeInts.amount];
public void loadMap() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map1.txt"));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null){
        int y = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++){

            //Error
            charmap[x][y] = line[x];
            //
        }
        y++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `line[x]` is reserved for arrays. A String is not an array. You could use the [`String#charAt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) and write:

```
charmap[x][y] = line.charAt(x);
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the errors and my program is now runable. Not working as intended though. I´l post something more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) to fetch character from strings..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
char[][] mapdata = new char[SomeInts.amount][SomeInts.amount];

public void loadMap() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("map1.txt"));
    String line = in.readLine();
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Load all the lines
    while (line != null){
        lines.add(line);
    }
    // Parse the data
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lines.get(i).length(); j++) {
            mapdata[j][i] = lines.get(i).charAt(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.